# Accessing PostgreSQL Fields via Indexing

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to access fields without explicitly providing the column name? For example, instead of the statement:

```
select (col1,col2,col3,...col42) from foo_table;
```

there's a (possible) alternative of:

```
select (1:42) from foo_table;
```

Comment: No, not possible. But this seems like a strange requirement and actually might indicate a bad (de-normalized) data model and the columns should actually be rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such syntax in Postgres' SQL.

You could always resort to having code that dynamically constructs the query for you before executing it, but that's about as good as it will get.